# Mirror the specific screen into a WPF control

Tags: .net, wpf, dwm

It is possible to show copy of specific display in a WPF control? I need to mirror display connected to the computer into a box in my APP (something like PIP on TVs). Currently I'm using the DWM API and DwmRegisterThumbnail functionality, it works fine, but it can handle only specific window as input, not entire screen, but I need to capture entire screen. I'm also tried to periodacally update target view using the Graphics.CopyFromScreen(), but it consumes a lot of CPU and memory + it is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it using Expression Encoder SDK. Check [Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.screencapture(v=expression.40).aspx) namespace.

As far as I know, with free version of expression encoder you have 10 minutes limit.

The other option is DirectShow. It's native library, but there are  .NET wrappers like [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html). Check samples [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/DirectShowSamples-2010-February.zip/download)

Here couple of other links from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/125636/How-to-make-screen-capture-video-using-Directshow):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Tanvon_DirectShowFilters.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

Without directx:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/capvidscrn.aspx